# Issue with if statement in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I use a radio button `plata` with two values `1` and `2` in my form and another input hidden `plata2` take one value depend to `plata`.

So i use this code inside in an existent function `total()`:

```
test = document.getElementById('plata').value;

if (test == 1) {
   document.getElementById('plata2').value=pretfinal;
}
else{
  document.getElementById('plata2').value=avansfinal;
}
```

But `plata2` take just first value, `else` never works? can help with this.

Comment: Try checking the value of test by logging it to the console to see if it is ever different from 1

Comment: We need to see the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

try "checked" instead of value:

```
test = document.getElementById('plata').checked;
if (test) {document.getElementById('plata2').value=pretfinal;}
else {document.getElementById('plata2').value=avansfinal;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have done is given both the radio elements the same id

```
test = document.getElementById('plata').value;
```

the code of line above will only select the 1st radio element, in your case the 1st one with value 1.
Hence leading to the if block and not the else block.

Here is a sample code for your requirement

https://jsfiddle.net/udkxynsn/

```
<label for='plate_1'>1</label>
<input type=radio name='plata' id='plata_1' value=1>
<br>
<label for='plate_1'>2</label>
<input type=radio name='plata' id='plata_2' value=2>
<br>
<input id='plata2'>
<br>
<br>
<div>CLICK</div>


<script>
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', test);


function test(){
  test = document.querySelector('[name=plata]:checked').value;
  if (test == 1) {
    document.getElementById('plata2').value="value1";
  }else {
    document.getElementById('plata2').value="value2";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check which of radio element is selected:

```
function total() {
            if (document.getElementById('plata').checked) {
                test = 1; 
            }
            else
            {
                test = 2; 
            }
            if (test == 1) { document.getElementById('plata2').value = pretfinal; }
            else { document.getElementById('plata2').value = avansfinal; }
        }
```